# Azure Cosmos DB GeoJson support - MultiPolygon, Feature

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, geospatial

I'm trying to understand what types of GeoJson objects I can store and work with in Azure Cosmos DB.
As per this documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial you can store any GeoJson as it is a valid JSON

But Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Spatial Namespace only has Point, Polygon and LineString geometry types. From this I gather that the geospatial queries like ST_DISTANCE and ST_WITHIN  will only work if we store Point, Polygon or LineString geometry types and not others. Is my understanding correct?

What is the workaround if I have a location field which is a multipolygon. Will I get out-of-the box support for querying something like - find all the entities which have one of the polygons intersecting a given polygon?

Thirdly, does Cosmos DB support indexing for feature and multipolygon types?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi. Did you get anywhere with this ? I've just posted a detailed related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60517677/cosmos-db-unexpected-validation-failures-from-geojson-obtained-from-uk-environme